# Moved baked Tag project form development to live and URLS not working

Tags: cakephp

Forgive me, I am still super new to cakephp. There are many things I haven't done yet. Migrating a baked aspects of my dev site to my live site is one of them. I followed a tutorial to add tags to my website. [Cake Tags Tut](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/tags-and-users.html) Everything on the dev site works perfect. Today I tried to move everything to the live site. I know its not the proper way to do it but I made a list of the changes I made and then moved the files and made the changes on the website. When I go to the URLs I need to use the tags I get an error. I have routes set up for the URLs and everything. Even though on the dev site I don't even need the routes for the URLs to work. Which makes me wonder about the baking process. After I gave the dev site the bake command the URLS were just there, it created all the skeleton code for the URL localhost/tags/add to work and I was able to start creating tags. Funny thing, all the functionality on the live site is there. When I create a post I can add tags to the DB and they pull fine when editing the post, they even show on the views. The only thing, I cant get to work are the index.ctp, add.ctp and edit.ctp for the tags. If you need any more info please just ask and I will provide it.

Route to define url for tags:

```
$routes->connect('/tags', ['controller' => 'Tags', 'action' => 'index']);
```

UPDATE:

I briefly turned on debug mode on the live site. Reloaded the page and got and error that has a bit more info.

*Error: The layout file Admin/Layout/Admin.ctp can not be found or does not exist.*

*Confirm you have created the file: Admin/Layout/Admin.ctp in one of the following paths:
/home/nerej/public_html/src/Template/Admin/Layout/Admin.ctp*

Hmmm, funny. In my dev site I was also having a similar issue.

Comment: Telling us specifically *what* error you're getting would be an excellent start. Have you read [the MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) suggestions for posting?

Comment: I understand its not a lot to go on. The error just says, "Error, An internal error has occurred. I did remove then replace the route that I added to my routes and the error changes to "the URL on this site can't be found". If that helps. I also checked the log files and did not find anything related to the tag controller or tags related. Ill put in my added route in to the question.

Comment: More details about "internal errors" should be logged in `logs/error.log`. The relevant output in there might well have no reference whatsoever to tags. Also, have you got the `debug` setting enabled in `config/app.php`?

Comment: Ill keep combing the log files. I am afraid to turn on debugging on the live site.

Comment: Not sure what the downside might be to turning it on long enough to do a single page load, when it's already broken...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, basically a naming convention error. The new error helped me track it down.

I was calling this in my funciton in TagsController:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('Admin');
```

But needed this:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->layout('admin');
```

Comment: Capitalization errors are common when your dev system is Windows (case insensitive file system) but the production system is Linux.